# Visualizing keywords from text using spaCY

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, visualization, spacy

I am using Textrank method for extracting keywords from text and I am able to print individual keywords along with their scores. But I am currently trying to output whole text with the keywords I extracted earlier be highlighted (encircled etc).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to give a set of keywords and have a visualization to highlight the keywords you specified?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure who your target audience is, but I think the simplest solution might be to programmatically generate hypertext (HTTP), for example, where the keywords are given a foreground/background color of your choice. In fact, this can see this as being quite useful.

SpaCy has [visualization tools](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy) but I believe they are targetted at providing specific NLP visualizations. I don't think they offer what you want, which seems to be a canvas for present information.

Oh! If you want to hack a solution, you can try this:
Create a custom entity type in SpaCy and have SpaCy report your keywords as your new custom entity type. Then you can use the [SpaCy Entity Visualizer](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent) to highlight your entities.

Comment: Custom Entity Recognition works well. Found some tutorials.

Comment: In that case, it would be great if you could upvote my answer (or accept it outright). If that's not possible, I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.